# How to PopAsync more than 1 page in Xamarin Forms Navigation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my app I'm pushing pages using a `NavigationPage` and at some stage I want to go back to a previous page in the stack. This is my structure:

NavigationPage > Page1 > Page2 > Page3 > Page4

How can I `PopAsync` back to Page2 directly from Page4 without going through Page3?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a workaround to this? I have found a method for popping all pages, but it is not what I am looking for. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21076/using-popasync-to-pop-two-or-more-pages-at-once

Comment: Not yet. I'm still trying to find a solution.

Comment: @FranciscoHermida have you resolve this issue i'm facing same problem \

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you have a count that you would like to pop, this works really well.

```cs
for (var counter = 1; counter < BackCount; counter++)
{
    Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
}
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it works instead of throwing an exception the way popping twice does and it avoids displaying the pages you are bypassing visually, so there is no unwanted visual artifacts.

Comment: This is not working on the latest Xamarin Forms stable version which is 2.3.4.247 today. [It is a known bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53179).

Comment: And by now fixed

Comment: Works like a charm now!

Comment: @caitlin what is BackCount how can i get this

Comment: BackCount is the number of pages you want to go back. This should be provided by you in someway.

Comment: Can simplify `for (var counter = 1; counter < backCount; counter++)` to `for (; backCount > 1; backCount--)`.  And if instead of `backCount` you have `goalPageIndex`,which is the index on nav stack of page you want to have showing, then `int backCount = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1 - goalPageIndex;`

Comment: why can I see the pages I'm bypassing when not using for? But when using for I can't see these views?

Comment: If you are like me and don't like indexing into lists, you can do some clever LINQing to get the second-to-last item on the NavigationStack:

`Navigation.NavigationStack.Reverse().Skip(1).Take(1).Single()` instead of `Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]`

Answer (score 4):

I came with a solution which can go back to an specific page as long as you have a reference to it:

```
protected async Task PopToPage(Page destination)
{
    if (destination == null) return;

    //First, we get the navigation stack as a list
    var pages = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();

    //Then we invert it because it's from first to last and we need in the inverse order
    pages.Reverse();

    //Then we discard the current page
    pages.RemoveAt(0);

    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        if (page == destination) break; //We found it.

        toRemove.Add(page);
    }

    foreach (var rvPage in toRemove)
    {
        navigation.RemovePage(rvPage);
    }

    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do the same thing - what I've wound up doing is a bit of a hack, but does work and keep the back button of page 2 going to page 1.

Basically,

```
var page3 = _navi.NavigationStack.FirstOrDefault(p => p is Page3Type);
if(page3 != null)
{
    _navi.RemovePage(page3);
}
await navi.PopAsync();
```

What this does is first, if present, remove page3.  Now that that's gone, it pops, and you're back at page 2.

Comment: If its possible for same page type to be on stack twice, use `LastOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked exceptionally well for me:

I set up a counter and threw a DisplayAlert to find out how many pages I needed to remove

```
var x = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count();
DisplayAlert("Page Count", x.ToString(), "OK");
```

And then used that to remove the number I needed to fall back.

```
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

here one update of the solution of @Alexei Humeniy

```
    public static async Task PopToPage<T>(INavigation navigation)
    {
        //First, we get the navigation stack as a list
        var pages = navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();

        //Then we invert it because it's from first to last and we need in the inverse order
        pages.Reverse();

        //Then we discard the current page
        pages.RemoveAt(0);

        var toRemove = new List<Page>();

        var tipoPagina = typeof(T);

        foreach (var page in pages)
        {
            if (page.GetType() == tipoPagina)
                break;

            toRemove.Add(page);
        }

        foreach (var rvPage in toRemove)
        {
            navigation.RemovePage(rvPage);
        }

        await navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a count that you would like to pop, this works really well for me.

```
    for(i=1; i < size; i++)
    {
    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
        {
            Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
        }
    }
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: You should explain why you treat Android differently.  Regardless, it is no longer necessary to do it this way (I assume there was some good reason at the time this was written); the accepted answer works fine on Android now.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 2 pages

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Worked fine in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise