# Navigation Issue in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to route pages A -> B -> C -> D, once I got into D, I need to use the navigation button back to page D -> A. I am trying to implement this scenario IOS and Android in Xamarin Forms.

Please help

Comment: Well you could either remove the pages using RemovePage method or call PopToRootAsync method to pop to the root page!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to PopAsync more than 1 page in Xamarin Forms Navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856116/how-to-popasync-more-than-1-page-in-xamarin-forms-navigation)

Comment: Please try to use this code
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            return true;
        }

Comment: Here is a helpful blog about achieving Navigation Service for Xamarin.Forms as well. https://mallibone.com/post/a-simple-navigation-service-for-xamarinforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case use the `Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();`

`Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();` This method pops all but the `RootPage` off the navigation stack, therefore making the root page of the application the active page.

`Navigation.PopAsync ();` This causes the `Page2Xaml` instance to be removed from the navigation stack, with the new topmost page becoming the active page.

The following doc explains well about `Xamarin.Forms` Navigation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical

Answer (score 1):

Inside the "D" page override the "OnBackButtonPressed" and inside the function iterate trough the pages you no longer need and remove them one by one.

Pseudo code:

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        foreach (var page in Navigation.NavigationStack)
        {

            //find the pages you want to remove
            Navigation.RemovePage(PageYouFound);
        }
        //Set new page
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can oveeride OnBackButtonPressed Event and use Navigation.PopToRootAsync

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();

    }
```